# Workflow in 1st List controlling items in the 2nd List - Possible?

Tags: workflow, list

May I know if it is possible to create workflow in the 1st list that control items in the 2nd List?

Comment: What kind of workflow? Visual Studio, SharePoint Designer, Nintex. Please elaborate. Also, what do you mean with 'control items'?

Comment: It can, your question is overly broad so it's difficult to answer with anything other than Yes.  Can you define the process a bit more?

Comment: Ok, a bit of details. I am actually doing a workflow in both  SharePoint Designer 2007 and Visual Studio 2008. I need a workflow, which is currently assigned to the 1st List to move a item from the 2nd list to the 1st List. From what I know, Workflow can only be assigned to a single list and it can only control items ('e.g. moving item from this list to another) - do let me know if I have know wrongly.) I was also thinking of having the 1st list workflow to modify values of items in the 2nd list too (This is part of the 'control items' operations)

Comment: Actually, I am looking for something similar. I posted a question (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19960/changing-the-value-of-a-field-in-another-list-from-a-form-library) that you can have a look but not exactly the same question as yours cause I am not moving any items from one List to another.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a Designer workflow which can be configured on one list so that when items are added or modified you can handle another list easily using actions "**Create list item**", "**Update list item**".

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with help of an event receiver along with (or instead of) a workflow. You can refer to my article here http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=649

Use the workflow to handle task/approval routing. Use event receiver to move data.

In the above article I have used the event receiver to move custom content types, you could use it with modifications to deal with lists.