# Changing the value of a field in another List from a Form Library

Tags: workflow, list, infopath, form

I have the following scenario:
I have one SharePoint List - List_A and one SharePoint form - Form_A

List_A has two columns (ConfigItem and ConfigValue) and it contain a few configuration settings.
**Example**
ConfigTitle: ProjectA_ID
ConfigValue: 1

In my Form_A, it is basically a form library whereby Info-Path form was stored. When a user create a new form, the form will retrieve the current ConfigValue (from List_A) based on ConfigTitle = 'ProjectA_ID' and display to the user using the form's text field.

When the user submit the form, that number will be recorded into the form and a workflow (or something else - using InfoPath form rules?) will update the ConfigValue (in List_A) by adding 1 to it. So if the user create the form see a value 5, then when user submit the form, the ConfigValue will become 6.

So, my question is how should I proceed to create such solution for the above scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do this using SharePoint List web services and CAML. The link below should help.

http://blog-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2009/07/summary-how-to-programmatically-update.html

Comment: +1 even though I doubt I am going to use it as I will be changing the way I change the value of a field in another list from a form library but appreciate your solution.